# Is it possible to omit the verb in Futur I?

Tags: future, auxiliary-verb

When using to future tense with an adjective, is it possible to omit the auxiliary verb?
My examples are:

> Es wird regnerisch oder sonnig, das hängt vom Wetter ab.
>
> Es wird regnerisch oder sonnig sein, das hängt vom Wetter ab.

The first example doesn’t sound odd to me.

Comment: @Bergmann Both sentences are correct from a grammatical point of view. Though, both sentences are rather weird. The fact of being cloudy or sunny is called weather. So it doesn't make sense that it depends on the weather. When Germans say that it depends on the weather, they for instance refer to what they will do. Ex: "Ich fahre Rad oder gehe in Fitnessstudio. Das hängt vom Wetter ab." So, just say "Es wird regnerisch oder sonnig (sein)". Period. ;)

Comment: @Em1 actually there was something in whole context, but i've shortened the statement. Yes i know there must be an activity existing to talk about weather.

Comment: @Bergmann very often, that activity is having a lack of other topics to talk about. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sentence, *wird* is the main verb; and technically, it does not use future tense. (Future tense would be “Es wird regnerisch oder sonnig *werden,* …”, with the first *wird* now being the auxiliary verb.)

In the second sentence, *sein* is the main verb, and *wird* is the auxiliary verb.

A mostly literal translation into English would be:

> It *becomes* rainy or sunny, … (better: It *turns* rainy or sunny, …)
>
> It will *be* rainy or sunny, …